# How to install MBR on to harddrive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, grub, mbr

Little bit of background... And i may be incorrect.
Someone before me, installed the MBR on one hard drive & the Windows 2008 OS on another ard drive. So when the hard drive with the MBR went belly up, the OS would not boot. Is there a way to install an MBR on the working HD containing the OS?

Should I use GRUB or something? Would that be the easiest solution?

I have tried using the repair disk like in this tutorial (http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/20864-mbr-restore-windows-7-master-boot-record.html) but there are no listings at this step (http://www.sevenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/25674d1251414836-mbr-restore-windows-7-master-boot-record-mbr_04.png)

Thanks!

Comment: I guess a simple repair using the install disk wouldn't do it? Just throwing it out there, I am not familiar with Windows 2008

Comment: @Jack, i was hoping that to be the case, but when I go through the process, there is no OS in the list.

Comment: I have never had to do a repair with W7, let alone W2008, only XP so I think I may be way off base with the assumption of running the install program, and choosing the repair option, since it sees another install already in place. It sounds though since the MBR is gone from that drive, it fails to see the OS at all?. If so, has anybody tried an overlay install like what could be done with W98?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 2008 (As up of Windows XP) sometimes when you install, it creates something like "boot partition" where Windows put all boot related stuff on it. If that is the case, you may have a problem because no aditional space will be available, and it may not work with grub.

If its only the MBR that is missing, the Windows 7 Master Boot Record recovery would work fine as GRUB does.

So for helping you making it work, if you have any way to resize the partition down, you can install another windows in parallel. This *SHOULD* make windows detect this Windows 2008 installed on another disk and create a menu entry for it on the new windows. So it would work on the same disk. After that you can edit the bootmanager menu (Open msconfig using execute on  Start Menu) and remove the new windows entry. So you would have a direct boot for your Windows 2008 without the other HDD.

This method has a side-effect, you will have part of your disk ocuppied by that stuff.

Also, you can try to use **bootrec** tool (included on windows, and use with other windows setup) with the option RebuildBCD to try to rebuild. Another way is using **EasyBCD**. I never tryed these two before, so use with caution and always make a backup of your stuff before doing anything!

I Hope I helped.

Comment: Thats a pretty good idea. I will give it a go (the resize & add do an install see if that works).

Comment: It's a [system volume](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/boot-and-system-volumes.html).